# Especificar idioma con MYSql - STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito parsear un texto a una fecha con **MySql**. El problema está en que el texto a parsear es del estilo: "`03-ene-17`".

He utilizado la función STR_TO_DATE de la siguiente forma:

```
STR_TO_DATE('03-ene-17', '%d-%b-%y');
```

El problema está en que la función por defecto solo reconoce las abreviaturas en inglés, por lo que no es capaz de parsear mi string.

Puedo modificar mi entrada para ir cambiando las abreviaturas en castellano por las abreviaturas inglesas. Pero quiero saber si hay alguna otra forma un poco más elegante de hacer esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma que se me ocurre es reemplazando el mes a la vez que formateas:

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('03-ene-17', '-ene-', '-Jan-'), '%d-%b-%y') AS FECHA
```

funciona, pero es laborioso porque tendrías que hacerlo para cada mes. Si es para implementar en una query de uso frecuente no sería muy práctico, pero si es para crear un campo tipo date en una tabla que almacene la fecha en un formato más moldeable (bastante aconsejable) puede servir.

Quizás a alguien se le ocurra un modo más sencillo.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero tengo que aplicarlo a muchos datos y es lo que dices, para uso frecuente no es muy práctico. Al final he acabado modificando los datos para que la función los pueda parsear.  He acabado utilizando: `update tabla set campoFecha = replace(campoFecha, '-ene-', '-Jan-')  WHERE campoFecha LIKE '%-ene-%';`

Comment: Creo que es lo mejor @Galbi, así puedes acceder más fácilmente a los datos, me alegro de que te haya servido. Aunque sólo como consejo, es mejor que los campos de fecha en la tabla tengan un formato date o datetime, para mejorar la integridad de la base de datos y facilitar las consultas, sobre todo cuando las tablas van creciendo con el tiempo.